# Checking New or Changed Entries in Weekly CSV File in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Each week I get a csv file that has 26 fixed columns. Each row of the file is a unique entry and a task.

Assuming the script interacts with two csv files: `New_Weekly_Data` and `Weekly_Data_yyyy_mm_d`d.

Each CSV is has one column marking if the task is closed with `Boolean` entries of `TRUE/FALSE`.

I'm trying to wrap my head around making something that:

1. Reads the new data (done)
2. Fetches the most recent data on record (done)
3. Compares the two to see (stuck)
   3a. If a task's completed column has changed from FALSE to TRUE
   3b. If new tasks have been added since the previous week.
4. Output a list of anything that is different between the two CSVs with respect to point 3. (stuck)
5. Save the new data with a tag of `Weekly_Data_yyyy_mm_dd (done)`

I've tried googling around for comparing dataframes. The main part where I am getting stuck is that the compare methods want the dataframes to be the same shape. The few outputs I have managed to get working seem to show all data entries when the list should be showing just the differences.

Edit: Was able to solve 3.b with `new = df2[~df2.index.isin(df.index)]`

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you read the following notices, it will be better to get an answer.:[mre]

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will return only the records whose status has been updated from false to true in new data

```
changed_tasks = df[(df['Completed'] == 'FALSE') & (df2['Completed'] == 'TRUE')]
```

[image: Sample]